# transom of hypocrisy

Tags: comprehension

Source: [Russia Wants Texas and Puerto Rico to Secede](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2015/09/24/russia-wants-texas-and-puerto-rico-to-secede.html)

Example:

> As such, if you’re a secession movement in the West, you’ll find a ready, willing audience in Moscow—but if you expect to find any Chechens, Tatars, or Siberians seeking their own sovereignty, your disappointment will find **a transom of hypocrisy** too thick to cross.

I really don't understand what the author is trying to say with that expression. I checked all the meanings that this word has and it doesn't seem like any of them have anything to do with the way it is used in this news article.

Comment: It is structurally analogous to "a mud-puddle of hypocrisy too wide to leap over".   The transom is the area above a doorway where one often finds a window. It thus refers (part-for-whole) to the width of the doorway's threshold.  What the passage seems to be saying is that Moscow will champion secessionist movements in the West but not on its own turf.  You won't find Chechens, Tatars, or Siberians in a room at the Kremlin, discussing their secession. That is hypocritical, and western secessionists would have to deal with the hypocrisy.

Comment: @TRomano On you argument *thick* might refer metonymically to the *depth* of the threshold; but it's still an inappropriate use of the metaphor. What's in play here is the transom light, which would have to be characterized as too *narrow* to admit a visitor.

Comment: @StoneyB: My opinion of that sentence is summed up by "mud-puddle". I wouldn't want to hold too firmly to any opinion about what the author may have been thinking, though I do think you are right about the abuse of "disappointment":  "to your disappointment you will find ..."

Comment: But your reading does make sense: ... to your disappointment you will find a transom of hypocrisy too thick *for them* (Chechens, Tatars, Siberians) to cross.

Comment: @TRomano I'm pretty confident in my assessment of the author's thought pattern: you can find something of the sort in virtually every sentence in the article. Journalism doesn't change!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ... your disappointment will find a transom of hypocrisy too thick to cross.

Oh, dear.

This is a case of slapdash writing. The author has extracted the word *transom* from the expression *over the transom* without stopping to consider what *transom* really means.

A *transom* is a structural crossbar: in this case an architectural member which closes the top of a doorframe and separates it from a window above it. That *transom window* or *transom light* is not merely decorative: it permits light to enter from the space above a closed door, and in the days before air conditioning it was common for the transom window to be openable, to allow air to circulate. In consequence, an open transom window provided a means of passing documents and small parcels into an office even when the door was closed. To this day we commonly say that manuscripts submitted by authors too shy to present their work in person, or documents presented outside of business hours, have come in “over the transom”. Publishers in particular characterize unsolicited manuscripts as *over the transom*.

Your author, a professional writer, is undoubtedly familiar with the expression *over the transom*, and seizes it as an apt metaphor for someone who attends a conference without being invited. Unhappily, he appears to think that a transom is some sort of barrier: a high counter, perhaps, which prevents visitors from penetrating to the offices beyond unless they are admitted by a receptionist or guard. He builds on this misunderstanding of *transom* to characterize it as a “thick” barrier composed of “hypocrisy” which secessionist would-be attendees from inside Russia cannot cross.

Note that *disappointment* is also abused in this clause: it is not your disappointment but your desire to attend which encounters this barrier, ***to your disappointment***.

Comment: I agree entirely, but it's barely possible that the writer was thinking of a threshold of hypocrisy and had a brain fart. That wouldn't account for the use of thick, though.